# Angular nesting same controller

Tags: angularjs

Hi is it a good practice to have controller within a controller in angular?

For Example:

The body tag of my html has a controller called "CommonCtrl" within the html tag i'm loading a template using includes and inside the template i reuse the same controller.

Code:

**Index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="commonCtrl as vm">

 <header data-ng-include="'app/includes/header.html'"></header>

  <div ng-show="vm.showThisdiv">show this div</div>
</body>
```

**header.html**

```
<header id="header" ng-controller="commonCtrl as vm">
<span ng-show="vm.displayRegisterHeader" id="extr-page-header-space"> <span class="hidden-mobile">Already registered?</span> <a href="#/login" class="btn btn-danger">Sign In</a> </span>
    <span ng-show="vm.displayLoginHeader" id="extr-page-header-space"> <span class="hidden-mobile">Need an account?</span> <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-danger">Create account</a> </span>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `ngController` in *header.html*, Just remove the following line from *header.html*

```
<header id="header" ng-controller="commonCtrl as vm">
```